# NDB .order returns an empty result

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, bigtable

I have two entities in my database which are connected. We'll call them A and B. I have an instance of A in memory (we'll call him a), and the following query currently works:

```
B.query(B.parent == a.key).fetch(limit=None)
```

But the following code returns en empty set, even in dev mode with indexes being automatically created:

```
B.query(B.parent == a.key).order(B.foo, B.bar).fetch(limit=None)
```

I've tried every combination I can think of, and I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Have you checked that `B` contains `foo` and `bar` properties?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the fields in question were made as TextProperty by a previous dev, which are un-indexable, and thus un-searchable.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
B.query(ancestor=a.key)
```

I don't believe any of the snippets you posted will even work.